# Gson - Json string to list of pojo

Tags: java, gson

I have this JSON response that I want to convert to equivalent list of pojo objects using Gson.

```
{
 "title" : "Java Generics and Collections",
 "formattedPrice" : "INR 460.00",
 "source" : "abc"
}, 

{
 "title" : "Java Generics and Collections",
 "formattedPrice" : "INR 460.00",
 "source" : "xyz"
}
```

**Product.java**

```
public class Product {

   private String title;

   private String formattedPrice;

   private String source;

   //Getters and setters

 }
```

This might be very basic but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: That JSON isn't valid. It appears that you have an array but you are missing the `[` and `]`

Comment: I only have this so it sounds like it is not possible to convert to pojos@LeeTaylor.  it works if I add `[]`

Comment: What is a pojo? Also, just noticed, are you using Java or Javascript, or both?

Comment: @LeeTaylor plain old java object

Comment: Are you using Javascript or Java? You know they're not really related...

Comment: java @LeeTaylor

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Product> products = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<List<Product>>(){}.getType());
```

But you have to structure you Json like a list, see bellow:

```
[
    {
        "title" : "Java Generics and Collections",
        "formattedPrice" : "INR 460.00",
        "source" : "abc"
    }, 
    {
        "title" : "Java Generics and Collections",
        "formattedPrice" : "INR 460.00",
        "source" : "xyz"
    }
]
```

You can use this [site](http://www.jsonlint.com/) to validate your json.

Comment: This is what leeTaylor suggested in comments

Comment: List<String> != List<Product>

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the [Gson User Guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Array-Examples)

Assuming the JSON is a valid array (the JSON you gave is missing the square brackets):

```
[
    {
     "title" : "Java Generics and Collections",
     "formattedPrice" : "INR 460.00",
     "source" : "abc"
    }, 

    {
     "title" : "Java Generics and Collections",
     "formattedPrice" : "INR 460.00",
     "source" : "xyz"
    }
]
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Product>>(){}.getType();
Collection<Product> productCollection = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);

System.out.println("RESULTS: "+productCollection.toString());
```

Here is the `Product` class I used:

```
public class Product {

    private String title;

    private String formattedPrice;

    private String source;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getFormattedPrice() {
        return formattedPrice;
    }

    public void setFormattedPrice(String formattedPrice) {
        this.formattedPrice = formattedPrice;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [title=" + title + ", formattedPrice=" + formattedPrice
                + ", source=" + source + "]";
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
RESULTS: [Product [title=Java Generics and Collections, formattedPrice=INR 460.00, source=abc], Product [title=Java Generics and Collections, formattedPrice=INR 460.00, source=xyz]]
```